# Blog Posts Wordpress Customizing

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, position

I am creating my own custom theme from scratch and have run into a bit of trouble. On the blog page, each time a new post is displayed, it is smaller than the last. This is due to me setting the width of the blog post to 33.3%. Also each blogpost gets displayed slightly right of the one previous to it. How can I have each blog post be 33.3% of the content area and be displayed side by side, 3 per row? I am using wordpress functions to call each blog post. I am only displaying the blog posts thumbnail and when you click the thumbnail it takes you to the post. So basically 3 images side by side.

[BONUS]: How could I get text to display horizontally and vertically on hover over each blog post image?

I know this is a lot to ask, but I have been trying to work this out for days. A JS Fiddle or Codepen would be greatly appreciated.

Index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
        <div class="blog-posts">
             <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                 <div id="page-content">   
                     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                         <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                             <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                 </a>   
                                     <?php endwhile; ?>   
                 </div>             
       </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: There's no way to run PHP scripts in JSFiddle as this service is mostly client side.

Comment: the php is only to call the blog posts but if someone just uses a mockup for that blogpost with html that's what I mean. Not actually using php, but just creating a visual with divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/) and do something like this :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
        <div class="blog-posts">
             <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                     <div id="page-content">   
                         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                             <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                             <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                         </a>   
                     </div>
                 </div>  
             <?php endwhile; ?>           
       </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Take care to remove the `width: 33.33%;` CSS rule and close your `<div>` tags in the loop, not after.

Hope it helps

**[EDIT]**

See this link for more information about how to use column classes with bootstrap : [grid example basic](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)

**[EDIT #2]**

You could do it without bootstrap but it will be a bit more difficult. You'll have to set the "display" to "inline-block" and set the width of the divs with taking care of the inherit margin of these tags. In this example, I had to set it to 32%. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tp06s4wu/)

Comment: what should I do instead for the width?

Comment: Use the bootstrap classe "col-md-4".

Comment: Is there a way without bootstrap? I have no experience with it. :P

Comment: Bootstrap is the easiet way I know but I think you could do it the hard way. Wait a minute, I'll show you an example.

Comment: But the real solution is to use bootstrap who will help you to build your pages responsively.

Comment: Hmm okay, I think I will take your advice and use bootstrap. Thanks for the help. :) I will see what I can do.

Comment: As a side note, why does wordpress create a empty like blog post above my single post page? How can I get rid of that? The only way to see it is if you put a border around the post. It is a very odd behavior. It uses the same code as here...

Comment: I don't know. You should ask a new question for this and show the code of the page.

Comment: I was thinking the same, however 90 min question limit :P

Comment: Is  there the same loop in the code of the single blog post page ?

Comment: Yeah but with content, category and time.

Comment: Should we move to chat?

Comment: Ok. maybe you'll find a solution by dig into the single.php file of the default theme. Copy it in your theme to know if it's a problem with your custom code.

Comment: Like twentysixteen or something?

Comment: Yes, as you like. I got to go. Good luck ! = )

Comment: I fixed the issue with each blogpost displaying smaller and smaller next to the previous one. I had a container class in my header and a container class in my loop so it looped over and over again. When I closed the container from my header in my footer and removed the code from my php files it works great.